# Linking two Executable to read and write data

Tags: exe, ipc, executable, qtp

First of all let me clear you all what am trying to achieve.

I have an exe which gives me some information when I supply the required data.

I cannot make any changes to the UI of that exe.

Now here are the first parameters that I set:
Electric Parameters
[image]

After setting the parameters I give some command through text box and receive the reply in the text area.

Here's how:Input Commands
[image]

I will then read each data and write into an excel manually.

Can I automate this whole process?

If so how?

I have thought of Inter Process Communication, but not finding any start.

Also got some guidance on using QTP (a testing tool).

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The question is regarding how to automate through QTP, which is a very basic level query. Can't explain each and every concept. However, would try to give some important steps.

Load the required addin...

1) Select all the addins at the start in QTP. Try Tools==> Object spy. Then you would understand which technology the exe is built on. Once this is identified, you need to select only that addin whenever you want to automate that application

2) Launch exe through QTP ==>

```
SystemUtil.Run (PathOfExe)
```

3) Read Fields==>

```
Window("Window").Field("Field").GetROProperty("Value") OR
Window("Window").Field("Field").Set "Command"
```

4) Read the output ==>

```
Dim Var
Var == Window("Window").Field("Field").GetROProperty("Value")
```

5) Write the values in excel ==>

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

Hope this helps for a start. You should try solutions of different sorts. Let us know if you come across any specific code related issues.

Comment: I'm starting with QTP. Let's see how it goes.